# $\int_{b_L}^{b_H} (x^z+k)^{(1/z)} dx$?

Tags: integration

I am trying to compute the definite integral $\int_{b_L}^{b_H} (x^z+k)^{(1/z)} dx$, with $z<1$ and $k>0$ and $0<b_L<b_H$.

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

Edit: here is my attempted solution, is this wrong?

(1) Substitute $y=x^z+k$.

(2) The lower bound on $y$ is $c_L=b_L^z+k$, the upper bound is $c_H=b_H^z+k$

(3) The definite integral becomes, $\int_{b_L}^{b_H} (x^z+k)^{(1/z)} dx=\int_{c_L}^{c_H} y^{(1/z)} dy$.

(4) Now, we can integrate: $\int_{c_L}^{c_H} y^{(1/z)} dy=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}y^{1+\frac{1}{z}}|_{y=c_L}^{c_H}=\frac{z}{1+z}(c_H^{\frac{1+z}{z}}-c_L^{\frac{1+z}{z}})$.

---

Edit 2: Right, this doesn't work because I replaced $dy=dx$ instead of the correct transformation $dy=zx^{z-1}dx$, which makes the method above fail as both $x$ and $y$ are in the transformed integral. But this means the substitution method would work for,

$\int_{b_L}^{b_H} (x^z+k)^{(1/z)} x^{1-z} dx$. Is there a distribution with pdf proportional to $x^{1-z}$? Then this would be the expectation of the function above across that distribution.

Comment: Is $e$ a variable or Euler's number (the exponential function)?

Comment: No, sorry, let me change it to a different symbol, say $x$.

Comment: See Ted's previous question ... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026691/

Comment: In substitution, you cannot just replace $dx$ with $dy$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, denote our Integral by $I(k,z,b)$. This calculation holds for all $b>0$

As a first step we  pull $k^{1/z}$ out of the brackets and rescale $x/k^{1/z}=y$ 
Our Integral is now given by:

\begin{align}
I(k,z,b)=k^{2/z}\int_0^{b/k^{1/z}}\left(y^z+1\right)^{1/z}dy
\end{align}

Now we the important part comes:

Substitute $y^z+1=q$. 
We obtain \begin{align} 
I(k,z,b)=\frac{k^{2/z}}{z}\int_1^{b+1}q^{1/z}\left(q-1\right)^{1/z-1}dq
\end{align}

Shifting $q\rightarrow -(p+1) $ , we arrive at

We get

\begin{align} 
I(k,z,b)=\frac{(-1)^{1/z-1}k^{2/z}}{z}\int_0^{-b}(1-p)^{1/z}p^{1/z-1}dp
\end{align}

Now it is clear from the [definition of Incomplete Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) that

\begin{align} 
I(k,z,b)=\frac{(-1)^{1/z-1}k^{2/z}}{z}B(-b,1/z,1+1/z)
\end{align}

Comment: See edit above. We're using similar logic but getting different solutions, I'm not sure why.